# Computing algebraic de Rham cohomology

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, de-rham-cohomology

> Let $R=\mathbb C[x,y]/(y(x-a)(x-b)-1)$ where $a,b$ are distinct complex numbers. Show that the cohomology of the de Rham complex $$0\to R\to \Omega_{R/\mathbb C}\to 0$$ is $\mathbb C$ in degree zero and $\mathbb C^2$ in degree one.

I have no experience in computing de Rham cohomology whatsoever (maybe except the case $R=\mathbb C[x]$, not with quotients), but first I need to at least identify $\Omega _{R/\mathbb C}$ and to write down to write the map $R\to \Omega_{R/\mathbb C}$. How do I do that?

Comment: Can you check your source if your equation is $y(x-a)(x-b)-1$ instead? Otherwise, I do not think you have $C^2$ in degree one if $b=0$.

Comment: @Youngsu Thanks, it was a typo.

Comment: $R$ is the ring of rational functions $f(x)$ of the form $\tfrac{g(x)}{(x-a)^m (x-b)^n}$,  for $g$ a polynomial. The differential takes $f(x)$ to $f'(x) dx$. What have you learned in calculus about derivatives and integrals of rational functions?

Answer (score 2):

You have $R=\Bbb C[x,y]/(F(x,y))$ for your given polynomial $F(x,y)$.
The differentials $\Omega_{R/\Bbb C}$ form an $R$-module, generated by
symbols $dx$ and $dy$ subject to the single relation
$F_x(x,y)\,dx+F_y(x,y)\,dy=0$ where $F_x$ and $F_y$ are partial derivatives.
The map $d:R\to\Omega_{R/\Bbb C}$ takes $g(x,y)$ to $g_x(x,y)\,dx+g_y(x,y)\,dy$.

The kernel of $d$ certainly contains the elements of $\Bbb C$. What you now need to
do next is to show that if $g$ is a polynomial with $(g_x,g_y)=(hF_x,hF_y)$ for
some polynomial $h$, then $g\in\Bbb C$. Over to you!

Comment: So do I not need to know explicitly what $\Omega_{R/\mathbb C}$ is isomophic to? And just to make sure I understood what you wrote in the second paragraph: is this argument supposed to show that $\ker d\subset \mathbb C$, and since $\ker d$ is the cohomology in degree zero, that would finish the first part? So we take $g$ from the kernel, meaning that $g_xdx+g_ydy$ is an $R$-multiple of $F_xdx+F_ydy$, that's how you got the equality of pairs? And also should we write $\overline g$, $\overline h$, $\overline F_x$ etc. everywhere since $R$ is a quotient ring?

Comment: I was trying to avoid quotients and express everything in terms of polynomials. Indeed the $0$-cohomology is the kernel of $d$ and the $1$-cohomology is the cokernel. In the last line I should have said that $g\in C+(F(x,y)$. @user437309

Comment: But if $g\in \mathbb C+(F(x,y))$, then how does this show (if it does) that $\ker d\subseteq \mathbb C$? Or is the point of showing $g\in \mathbb C+(F(x,y))$ different?

Comment: $g\in\Bbb C+(F(x,y))$ is the same as saying that $\overline g\in\Bbb C$ within the quotient ring $R$.

Comment: I see, thank you. That's why the abuse of notation (talking about residues as the actual elements of the ring) is confusing for me. I will try to prove that inclusion, but meanwhile do you have any hints on how to find the cokernel? I guess that's where we would need to identify $\Omega_{R/\mathbb C}$...

Comment: Isn't $\Omega_{R/\mathbb C}$ just $Rdx$, by an argument from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3201360/characterizing-a-module-of-kahler-differentials)? Then the kernel of the last map has rank 1, how could its quotient have rank 2? Probably I misunderstand something.